# Updating varbinary with a binary array

Tags: c#, asp.net, binary

I'm trying to update a `varbinary` in my MSSQL with a binary array of an image.
I tried using this query, which doesn't seem to work:

```
string sql = "UPDATE table SET bdata='" + imagedata + "' WHERE ID=1";
```

This is just an example of a query I used. Why doesn't it work? And I prefer not using `SqlCommand`.

bdata is of type `varbinary(max)` and imagedata is a `byte` array.

What am I doing wrong that it's not working? An exception tells me I need to use `CONVERT` or something like that..

This is the given exception when trying to run it:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't seem to work_? You get any exception or error message? You need to use `+` just before `WHERE ID=1` as well. Also you should use it in a string like `+ WHERE ID=1` (WHERE ID=1 part should beetween `"` since it is a string)

Comment: What is the type of `imagedata`? If you "*prefer not using SqlCommand*" - then how do you executing your query? Add more details.

Comment: Added variable types.

Comment: I do use SqlCommand but in another class that I trigger by sending a string of the query I want.

Comment: Use parameters! Then you can just set the parameter value to a `byte[]` rather than messing with strings like you are here, that's also open to injection!

Comment: But how can I send it like what I have done? With `"bdata='" + imagedata + "'"`

Comment: First, *never* construct SQL statements by concatenating strings. There are various security and performance issues. Second, you can't pass a byte array as a string. Use parameterized queries as shown in the duplicate question and pass the byte[] value to a SqlDbType.VarBinary typed parameter.

Comment: I managed doing it while sending the query and a `SqlParameterCollection` to the update method. Thanks!